# Sound Logout Ubuntu 12.04 & Mac OS 9 Theme

Tags: 12.04

It is possible for a script to shut down or log off, make a sound I want, such as Windows 95, Millennium or 2000
even if it was possible with the new 11.10 but the 12.04 does not emit any sound at shutdown
thanks
and its system is much better than mac and virus' windows ¡keep it up!
one more thing.
can I leave my system as Mac OS 9
is that strikes me Mac OS 9.
Icons, Sounds, GTK theme, all as Mac OS 9
PLEASE

Answer (score 1):

Here's two links:

- http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/mac-os-x-lion-for-ubuntu-1204-precise.html
- http://techmix.net/blog/2011/07/17/how-to-change-login-sound-in-ubuntu-11/

Comment: Wrong system ;) He wants Mac OS 9, which is an entirely different beast than UNIX-based Mac OS X. For the old gnome/mate there are some themes (like http://ubuntu-art.org/content/show.php?content=110444&foo=b4ca6a2f44ac2), but nothing shows up for gnome3 or unity.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: So what????? What if anybody ask MacOS 1.1 theme??? I think this answer is acceptable.